# Can I configure the Touch Bar to type my email address?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, copy-paste, touch-bar

I still have to manually type my e-mail address many times a day, and proofread each time and it is exhausting.

I do have a **Text Replacement** set up in my **Keyboard System Settings**, so that when I type "`@@@`" it types my email address automatically *in most cases*.

But this isn't always working. There are apps such as password managers and some forms on the internet I frequently come across, where typing my shortcut does absolutely nothing.

As someone who rarely uses the Touch Bar (except maybe for volume), I think it would be great to be able to use some of this vast unused space to paste short clippings of text into a field on a webpage or an app. Ideally in a way that can be programmed.

**I haven't found a way to do that, is it possible either via system or a third-party app?**

Comment: I don't have a Touch Bar, so can't test this as an answer. Better Touch Tool can respond to Touch Bar triggers. Confident that would work for filling web page forms. Less so for modal windows for which I use Keyboard Maestro. So might need both.

Comment: With Touchbar should come Touch ID so why not use it for logging-in/password entering?

Comment: @AivarPaalberg As I said in my question, there are apps and forms on the internet where it doesn't work. The touch bar is always 50% empty space and a "paste email" key would be incredible useful

Comment: Still unclear what the problem is. After editing the header by replacing password with e-mail address the first paragraph still reads: “I still have to manually type my password many times a day, and proofread each time and it is exhausting”. Is this just non-related complaining or something which is part of the problem.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg Apologies for my early mistakes, I have corrected them